# Validate password is false after correct password

Tags: php, yii2

So, I try to make a login, but when the password is compared the hash in the database, ti returns false. And I am 100% sure the password is right.
Here is my User.php:

```
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        if ($this->findByUsername($this->username)->password) {
            return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->findByUsername($this->username)->password);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }
```

To be more specific, the function Yii::$app->security->validatePassword() returns false. The function password_verify() always returns false. Why? What should I do? What I do wrong.
One more information. This is my RegistrationForm.php

```
public function register()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $this->username;
            $user->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
            if ($user->save()) {
                return $user;
            }
        }
    }
```

Why it does not enter in if()? Why it doesn't validate? Please help.

Comment: Can you generate a hash for a sample such as `test` and post the hash here

Comment: "This is my RegistrationForm.php" - There's more to that method than you posted, right?

Comment: If you are storing password hash in DB I would check the length of password field in DB. If the hash is longer than field length it would be truncated when stored in DB and then the validation would always fail.

Comment: Aren't you hashing it twice? Setter is using the hasher and you are feeding it with already hashed password.

Comment: @Bizley but OP is assigning to `password` property directly. The `__set()` method in `yii\db\BaseActiveRecord` is implemented in a way that DB attributes are set directly instead of going through setter.

Comment: AR's properties are virtual, they use setters if present.

Comment: Anyway, I might be wrong but OP should just check it - either remove the setter or keep it and pass raw password there.

Comment: This is the hash of the password test:  $2y$13$9p3sw/he.pQBi0yClr7G4egdsygivPYgyKRtHV.kn66qocdgWyelG
After some var_dump() the problem is in LoginForm() in validatePassword()
'public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }'
!$user is false

Comment: @Bizley yes, AR properties from DB are virtual. They are stored in private property `$_attributes`. But if you check the implementation of [`yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::__set()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/fcaafd82f5ccdc391c15685ce0b635e2f6aed114/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L311) you can see that parent implementation of `__set()` is only called for virtual properties that are not attributes. The values of attributes are set directly.

Comment: https://github.com/FlaviusAga08/yii2.git
Here are the relevant files. Can you take a look?

Comment: @Bizley https://github.com/FlaviusAga08/yii2.git Here are the relevant files. Please, can you take a look?